# ¿Cómo validar si el textbox tiene alguna letra?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Lo que intento lograr es una validación sí en el textbox existe alguna letra, o solo son números, con una condición, después de hacer clic en enter si son solo números hará una acción y si tiene alguna letra otra.

```
if(soloNumeros == true)
 {
 // una acción
 }  
 else
 {
  //SI TIENE ALGUNA LETRA OTRA ACCIÓN
 }
```

Espero alguien pueda apoyarme, saludos y gracias anticipadas.

Les comparto mi código actual.

```
      int introducir_permitido = 0;

    private void txt1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (introducir_permitido == 0)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 64) //PERMITIR EL ARROBA
            {
                e.Handled = false;

                introducir_permitido = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        if (introducir_permitido == 1) // CUANDO VALOR ES 1 PERMITIR REALIZAR ENTER
        {
            e.Handled = false;

            int tamaño_texto = txt1.Text.Length;

            if (e.KeyChar == 13)
            {
               //AQUI QUISIERA VALIDAR SI SON SOLO NUMEROS O TIENE ALGUNA LETRA 

                string valor = txt11.Text.Replace("@", "");

                txt1.Text = valor;

                comparacion(txt1.Text);

                e.Handled = true;

                introducir_permitido = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar TryParse asi:

```
if (introducir_permitido == 1) // CUANDO VALOR ES 1 PERMITIR REALIZAR ENTER
    {
        e.Handled = false;

        int tamaño_texto = txt1.Text.Length;

        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
           //AQUI QUISIERA VALIDAR SI SON SOLO NUMEROS O TIENE ALGUNA LETRA 

            string valor = txt11.Text.Replace("@", "");
            int value;
            if (TryParse(valor,out value))
            {

              txt1.Text = valor;

              comparacion(txt1.Text);

              e.Handled = true;
            } else {
              e.Handled = false;
             // Despliega tu error aqui
            }

            introducir_permitido = 0;
        }
    }
```

Puedes implementar tu propia version de TryParse asi:

```
static bool TryParse(string s, out int value)        
{
    try
    {
        value = int.Parse(s);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        value = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias, ya lo intenté @alanfcm pero me muestra el error de "'int' no contiene una definición para 'TryParse'" ya lo modifiqué por Int32 y sigue apareciendo el mismo.

Comment: que lenguaje estas usando?

Comment: C# en vs2008 @alanfcm

Comment: Intenta con int.Parse.  ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: me lo está tomando como tipo bool "No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'int' en 'bool'"

Comment: puedes implementar tu propio tryParse. Ya edite otra vez

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77173/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-masha10).